# Google Data Studio ignoring Date Range dimension

Tags: looker-studio

I've brought a custom data source into Google Data Studio, but it's not responding to date filters. It brings in all of the data regardless of date filters.

Google's [documentation](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9272806?hl=en) says that the fix for this is to change the date range dimension in the "Data" tab, but this option isn't visible for me:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNER1.png)

How can I set the default date range dimension for this data source?

*The data source is the Gravity Forms API, which I am connecting to through Supermetrics' Custom JSON/XML Connector.*

Answer (score 0):

**Default date range** option exists below the **Rows per Page** and **Sort** options.

Check `Auto` in **Default date range** to filter out datasource with date range.

[image]